# MariaDB not able to change innodb_log_file_size

Tags: mariadb, innodb

I was getting errors while uploading images to my mysql database because the log file size was too small. So I am trying to increase it. I tried adding this to my /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size=2G
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
```

Then I moved the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files from /var/lib/mysql to /tmp.

Then I ran:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And I checked the value:

```
| innodb_log_file_size          | 50331648 |
```

But as you can see, it's still the default value.

Following Google's advice, I also checked:

```
| innodb_fast_shutdown | 1     |
```

I also checked the mysql error logs but found them to be empty.

So, why is this setting not getting applied?

Comment: Belongs in dba.stackexchange, where it will be declared dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size

Comment: What's the value of `Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written`?